# Connecting pipes

Tags: geometry, connections

Suppose we have three pipes in 3D and one end of a pipe mark as inlet and other end marks as outlet. We have to connect outlet edge with other pipe inlet edge.

Here is the visual representation of pipes:

[image]

In the above image, a green node is inlet and a yellow node is outlet.

Can anybody suggest me an algorithm that connect pipes as mentioned in a image?

Comment: What is the problem that you want to solve? What do you want the algorithm to do? Do you want a mathematical solution, a programatic solution, or just a conceptual solution? I see the pipes; I just don't know what the $problem$ is in getting them connected.

Comment: @poetasis Please tell me an algorithm that can connect pipes as shown in above image.

Comment: See or look for rotation and translation matrices.